# how can I fit iframe container full height

Tags: html, css

I have a website
http://www.modsagency.com/home

here after main menu the contain portion is loading from one of my another website. but the problem is it is loading by iframe and one scroll over there I want to remove scroll by fit this iframe full width, the main website scrolling no problem.

How can I fix by css, any tricks.

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I did overflow hidden, you can see it, but still now working.

Comment: Why would you want to put an iframe in a website anyway? It is not ideal. Try removing the height aspect for iframe and set it to 100%. Either that or remove both completely. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. try using `width:100%;` this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead light.css(Line No.710) in #wrapper properties just remove overflow:hidden and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Twix said it could be very useful for you to have the `width: 100%;` but I can also see some padding inside your CSS - which could lead to the problem with the width.